# Are Workflows/Process Builder/Apex Triggers specific to an App the person is using, or do they apply to all Apps?

Tags: page-layout, app, tab, setup

I just need to know if all existing rules, triggers, formulas, etc. will apply to any new app created in my org. This is what I mean by App:

[image]

What is the benefit of using the standard Sales app over creating any new customized one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflows/Process Builder/Apex Triggers specific to an App the person is using, or do they apply to all Apps?

Ans is. **Yes**, it is applicable to all the Apps.

Those rules are applicable to specific Objects. If we need to access objects from UI, we create tabs and you may think the `App` is a container of all these tabs.

The `App` is the group of tabs which is necessary for your/customer's benefit.

If, business need can be fulfilled by using standard Sales App then it's better to use standard one.

But, for other customized applications, other than Sales we need to create a separate App and give permissions to specific profiles who will be using those.